# Alternative for Automating amplify add function in AWS Amplify (no Headless Mode)

Tags: shell, automation, aws-amplify, aws-cli

I'm working with AWS Amplify and looking for a way to automate the `"amplify add function"` command, ideally in a headless or scriptable format. My goal is to integrate this into a larger automation script. Unfortunately, it seems that the Amplify CLI does not natively support headless mode for this particular command.

Is there any known workaround or alternative method to achieve this? Any suggestions or guidance on how to approach this automation would be very helpful.

Comment: i posted a Issue on aws-cli github repository : https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/13557 take a look !